# Is it possible to bind a [routerLink] to a div? Angular 2+

Tags: angular, routes

I am new to Angular and I have found no clear answers on this subject no matter what I search for.

This is currently working:

```
<div class="col-sm" (click)="brandListRoute()">
```

which directs to this function in my component:

```
brandListRoute() {
        this.router.navigate(['explore/brands']);
}
```

So this works perfectly, however when I first tried binding `[routerLink]` like this:

```
<div [routerLink]="['explore/brands']">  </div>
```

I can click on the div but nothing happens. So my question is, does a `[routerLink]` only work on things like `anchor tags` and `buttons` or is my above logic flawed?

Need to find the best solution for my problem. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes it can be attached to **div** tag, your route is probably wrong try add **/** in front of route.

```
<div [routerLink]="['/explore/brands']"> go to this location </div>
```

Comment: Great stuff! This worked first time, thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks. This works well. I just want to point out though that if you're not using the anchor tag then it will not show the URI on hover nor will the context menu options of  'Open in new tab', 'Copy URL', etc. be available.

Comment: Note: if you planning to bind ['state' to route](https://medium.com/ableneo/how-to-pass-data-between-routed-components-in-angular-2306308d8255) `<div>` will NOT bind data, however `<a>` will - verified in Angular 8.1 & 8.2

Comment: @VikramDeshmukh Does this mean, that if I would like to open in a new tab, binding routerLink to div will not work?

Comment: @Franva. Yes, to the best of my knowledge. However, I have moved away from Angular since and so I might not be aware of any new way of accomplishing this.

Comment: You should avoid this and prefer a (click) + navigate programmatically approach since it will make your div "focusable" and Chrome by default adds a black outline to focused elements.